# Missing number, treated as zero when using itemize

Tags: itemize

This is my code:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item {客户端发出登录请求}
\item {服务器返回一个随机值，并在会话中记录这个随机值}
\item {客户端将该随机值作为密钥，用户密码进行HMAC运算，然后提交给服务器}
\item {服务器读取用户数据库中的用户密码和步骤2中发送的随机值做与客户端一样的HMAC运算，然后与用户发送的结果比较，如果结果一致则验证用户合法}
\end{itemize}
```

When compile,throw this error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero
```

what should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: The first thing you should do is to show a small but *complete* example. And you should tell how you are compiling.

Comment: Please give a fully compilable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

I experience no problems of any kind as long as I issue the instruction `\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}` in the preamble, employ the `article` document class, and compile the test document with pdfLaTeX.

That said, don't encase the contents of each `\item` in matching curly braces. The curly braces are both unnecessary and undesirable; all they do is to create code clutter.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item {客户端发出登录请求}
\item 服务器返回一个随机值，并在会话中记录这个随机值
\item 客户端将该随机值作为密钥，用户密码进行HMAC运算，然后提交给服务器
\item 服务器读取用户数据库中的用户密码和步骤2中发送的随机值做与客户端一样的HMAC运算，然后与用户发送的结果比较，如果结果一致则验证用户合法
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```